# What was wrong in this command I always got this error #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: php

```
select prod_id, prod_code,prod_desc,brand_code,prod_cost,prod_image, category 
    from tbl_products 
    where prod_code in (SELECT DISTINCT prod_code, 
                               sum(del_qty + ret_qty) - SUM(sales_qty) as 'Stocks' 
                        from tbl_initial_inventory
                        GROUP BY prod_code)
```

Comment: Your sub-query should return only one column, currently, you are returning 2 columns.

Comment: sir Nigel Ren thank you very much for your response i learned also from the idea you share to me. Thanks very much sir..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sub query should return single column so server will able to compile your query properly.

This should be written like below.

```
select prod_id, prod_code,prod_desc,brand_code,prod_cost,prod_image, category 
from tbl_products 
where prod_code in (SELECT DISTINCT prod_code, 
                    from tbl_initial_inventory)
```

Comment: do you want 'Stocks'  from your sub query in select statement?

Comment: I try your code sir i  got the answers but what if i want to include the total qty per product code. Say on this product code i have a total of __ for del_qty, total of ___ for sales_qty. and total of ____ for ret_qty. My table has the following details . tbl_products  has prod_id, prod_code,prod_desc,brand_code,prod_cost,prod_image, category     whiletbl_initial_inventory has initial_id, prod_code,del_qty,sales_qty,ret_qty

Comment: okay use query like blow ---- select tp.prod_id, prod_code,prod_desc,brand_code,prod_cost,prod_image, category, qty.Stocks
from tbl_products  tp
 inner join (SELECT DISTINCT prod_code, 
                               sum(del_qty + ret_qty) - SUM(sales_qty) as 'Stocks' ,
                        from tbl_initial_inventory
                        GROUP BY prod_code) qty ON tp.prod_code = qty .prod_code

Comment: thanks very much sir Deepak appriciate your help. I works i will study your code how it works but thanks you very much sir for the help. I am new to this group and also to mysql that i found it hard to understand again sir thank you...